# JQuery select tr when all images in td are not example.png

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i select those tr's which all DONT have the example.png in one of their td's? Every image has an anchor, so i thought i may select by that...
i never worked with jquery before and its quite confusing^^

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td > a").parent().parent().css("background-color","lime");
});
```

Here one of my tr's but with only the first anchor/image (it is already too long):

```
<tr bgcolor='$color'>
    <td><a href='request.php?id=$requestid'>#$requestid [show request]</a></td>
    <td>$generation&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$custname&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$platform&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$phase&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$tmc&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$pcstroke&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$scstroke&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <a href='myurl.php?selection=" . $flowid."' title='new'>
            <img align='center' src='images/new.png'
                 alt='' style='width:20px; height:20px;' />
        </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    $status
    <td><b>$prelease</b></td>
</tr>;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your showing us serverside code, there's no image `example.png` in those TD's ?

Comment: Anyway `$('td:has(img[src*="example.png"])')`

Comment: there is a image, you have to scroll to the right it is just called new.png in there...
Thanks anyway! i believe now you select those td which have the example.png right? Is there a way to negate?

Comment: Moreover you have a `$status` between the last 2 `td`, outside the columns.

Comment: Of course there's a way to negate, using `:not()` -> `$('tr:not(tr:has(img[src*="example.png"]))')`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lbh2u0b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not` and `has`

```js
var allTrs = $("tbody tr"),
    nonExample = allTrs.not(':has(img[src*="example.jpg"])');
nonExample.css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>foo</td><td><img src="foo.jpg" alt="foo"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>example</td><td><img src="example.jpg" alt="example"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>bar</td><td><img src="bar.jpg" alt="bar"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>example</td><td><img src="example.jpg" alt="example"/></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select table's existing `img`, and then `parent` 3 times, as they are expected to be located within anchors `tr>td>a>img`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $images = $('table tr>td>a>img'); // Choose the right table selector
    $rows = $images.closest('tr');
    console.log($rows);
});
```

Comment: `closest("tr")` is so much cleaner than `parent().parent().parent()`

Comment: If it needs to be `example.png`, use @epascarello's answer (with `png` instead of `jpg`).